# Get individual completion of combined Futures

Tags: java, asynchronous, guava

I have two Futures that need to run in parallel, however, I had to make some computation when both have completed, but I also need to get metrics around when they complete individually:

```
ListenableFuture futureA = someFuture();
ListenableFuture futureB = someFuture();

Futures.addCallback(
  Futures.whenAllComplete(futureA, futureB).call(
    () -> {
        // Some computation with results of both futures
    }, executor),
  new FutureCallback() {
    onSuccess() {
      // log success
    }
    onFailure() {
      // log failure
    }
  }, executor);
```

I would like to log too when futureA completes and when futureB completes individually. Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: com.google.common.util.concurrent